# CSS Embedded Image as a link

Tags: html, css, image

I have a html page which is using the same icon many times, and so I have embedded that icon as a background-image in css.

In css, the class for the icon is like this:

```
.user {
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,...encoded png file...);
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
```

I display the icon using a`<span class='user'></span>` tag, so far, so good.

I want the icon to be a link to another page, but I can't make the icon look correct when I do this.

I have tried:

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img class="user" src=""></img></a>
```

but this draws a broken link icon over it in Explorer, it looks ok, but has a border in Chrome. It is obviously wrong.

I also tried:

```
<a href="www.google.com"><span class="user"></span></a>
```

and this works, but the mouse cursor does not change to a pointer when over the icon.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make the element block level (at least `inline-block`) to set the width/height and explicitly set the `cursor`. These two things are the key components.

```
.user {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,...encoded png file...);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block; /* set display so you can set width/height */
    cursor: pointer; /* ensure it shows the link cursor */
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#urlhere"><span class="user"></span></a>
```

So, you end up with an `inline-block` element which shows the image, and then you wrap that with an anchor. This is basically the same as wrapping an anchor around an `<img />`.

Alternatively, you could do this with just the `<a>`. You would use the exact same CSS, with this HTML:

```
<a href="#urlhere" class="user"></a>
```

Both should achieve what you're after. The difference between these two choices is mostly semantics.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help, both methods work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `class` attribute on the anchor tag.

```
<a href="#" class="user"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this one on your css

```
  cursor:pointer;/*Link with poniter*/

<a href="www.google.com"><span class="user" /></span></a>
```

Comment: How does this convert the icon to a link?

Comment: @Vimal Stan I supposed he mentioned about mouse cursor not showing, pls see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/RNXXx/)

**The HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="user"></a>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.user {  
    text-indent: -99999px;
    background: url("http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png") no-repeat top left;
    float: left;   
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Hope this is what you need.